# Filter in ManyToManyField with through

Tags: django

I have model:

```
class Player(models.Model) :
    ...
    teams = models.ManyToManyField("Team", through="PlayerTeam")

class Team(models.Model) :
    ...
    players = models.ManyToManyField("Player", through="PlayerTeam")

class PlayerTeam(models.Model) :
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    date_begin = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get all players who are playing in selected team (date_end is null). I tried this:

```
team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=id)
players = team.players.filter(date_end__isnull=True)
```

but it doesn't work, because field 'date_end' isn't in Player model

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
players = team.playerteam_set.filter(date_end__isnull=True).values_list('player', flat=True)
```

Comment: It returns list of players id. I want to get a list of players object

Comment: Do you need to apply any more queryset filters to it? If no, just use something `[tp.player for tp in team.playerteam_set.filter(date_end__isnull=True).select_related()]`.

Comment: I want add order by some field in Player model

Comment: Also I want to add some informations about player from PlayerTeam model

Comment: You can sort the list and add necessary info using Python itself.