# Filter on ManyToManyField intermediate table fields

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have an usual M2M with an additional field in the intermediate table:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name=u'Items', through='CustomerItem')

class Item(models.Model):
    pass

class CustomerItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='customer_items')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='customer_items')
    item_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get a queryset with all Items for a given Customer where `item_count > 0`. The only way I've found so far (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674687/filter-in-manytomanyfield-with-through)) is to filter the intermediate table and then make a list of objects with Python code, but I need a queryset (for a form `ChoiceField`).

Comment: Does `items = Item.objects.filter(customer_items__customer=customer, customer_items__item_count__gt = 0)` work?

Comment: @Bibhas seems working, please write an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here -

```
items = Item.objects.filter(customer_items__customer=customer, customer_items__item_count__gt = 0)
```

As you've added `related_name='customer_items'` to the `Item` foreign-key. You can access the `CustomerItem` related to any `Item` via `item.customer_items`. Rest is piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
Customer.object.filter(customeritem__item_count__gt=0)
```